Troubleshooting the 'View in Alertmanager' Button in MultiClusterObservability Email Notifications
This question concerns Openshift, but perhaps someone who simply deals with Kubernetes might be able to help. I have 2 clusters and on one of them I deployed Prometheus Alertmanager on Redhat ACM using MultiClusterObservability:
https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_advanced_cluster_management_for_kubernetes/2.3/html-single/observability/index
It's a simple configuration that collects alerts from all clusters and sends them via email. So, I invoke MultiClusterObservability which creates a StatefulSet, and the StatefulSet manages the pods.
apiVersion: observability.open-cluster-management.io/v1beta2
kind: MultiClusterObservability
metadata:
  name: observability
spec:
  enableDownsampling: true
  imagePullPolicy: Always
  observabilityAddonSpec:
    enableMetrics: true
    interval: 60
storageConfig:
  metricObjectStorage:
    name: thanos-object-store
    key: thanos.yaml
  storeStorageSize: 1Gi
  storageClass: xxx
advanced:
 retentionConfig:
  blockDuration: 2h
  deleteDelay: 48h
  retentionInLocal: 24h
  retentionResolutionRaw: 10d
  retentionResolution5m: 90d
  retentionResolution1h: 10d

The emails work great (after configuring alertmanager.yaml), but there's a generic "View in Alertmanager" button in these emails. With the aforementioned configuration, this button doesn't work by default. The URL under the button points to:
http://observability-alertmanager-0:9093/#/alerts?receiver=XXX
observability-alertmanager-0 - this is the name of the pod. As I mentioned, everything is deployed through MultiClusterObservability. Could someone guide me on how to fix this button (so it actually directs to the Alertmanager's address) or at least someone could point me to documentation that controls this, as I can’t find it in the official sources,
Thank you.
